# DTMF, DFT window length

Tags: matlab, dft, dtmf

We've got an assignment in school to create a DTMF decoder, but are having trouble understanding what needs to be done, and how. First of all we need to calculate the energy of the signal using convolution. We do it by making use of the window length and the absolute value of the input signal:

```
SmoothEnergyOfInputSignal = conv(abs(X), ones(1,winlen)/winlen); %moving average
```

Now, we don't know how to get the proper window length. The smoothed energy is used to segment the signal, and later to determine the different frequencies in the signal making use of basis vectors(?)
The dtmf-pulses are at least 40ms separated by at least 40ms of silence.
The sampling frequency is at 8kHz and our signal is about 17601 samples long.
We thought that by doing fs*0.04 we'd get the window length. 0.04=40ms, but now the smoothed energy signal is shifted so the  segments go beyond the maximum samples of the input signal.

```
[Sound, fs] = audioread('dtmf_all.wav');
winlen = fs*0.04 
E = conv(abs(Sound),ones(1, winlen)/winlen)
```

Long story short: How do we calculate the "correct" window length?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The instructions were updated, and we're not supposed to use convolution. We're supposed to use filter()